# Using PHP code snippet as a shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the plugin PHP Snippet in Wordpress. It's working fine, but the code contains a mistake that is stopping it from working properly.

The PHP code I'm trying to apply is the following:

```
$StartDate = strtotime('2016-05-10'); //Start date from which we begin count 
$CurDate = date("Y-m-d"); //Current date.
$NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", $StartDate)); //Next date = +2 week from start date
while ($CurDate > $NextDate ) { 
    $NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", strtotime($NextDate)));
}
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($NextDate)), "\n;
```

I need to use the "return" function for it to work properly, but simply replacing "echo" by "return" isn't working...

Could you please help?

Comment: Where's the starting `{`? I can only see the closing bracket `}`

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: @PedroLobito I edited to how I think it was supposed to look. The `while` got caught in the comment... Maybe that was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this returns compiler erros:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($NextDate)), "\n;
```

try this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($NextDate)). "\n;
                                        ^
```

you concatenate strings in php with a dot.

Comment: I've replaced the comma with the dot, but the result is the same: I get the correct date, but the result appears on the top of the page instead of the correct place where I've inserted the shortcode (with the PHP inside).
From what I've been able to check, Wordpress only allows the code to appear in the right place if the "return" function is used (instead of "echo")...

Comment: there is also a '}' in the middle of your code, the function will stop right there and return is never being called

Comment: You're also missing a closing double quote on `"\n`